# Setting a variable to a value in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

```
static int findPerson(String n, int NP, Friend[] giftGivers){

    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NP; i++){
    if (giftGivers[i].name == n){
            index = i;
    }
    }

    return index;
}
```

I have this code in Java for a method to search through an array of Friends to find the index number of the person with the name input by String n. however i have found that the index number does not set to the index number it is should be. Is it because it is in the if statement?

Comment: No need to continue the loop once you have found the person. `{ for(int i = 0; i < giftGivers.length; i++) if (...) { return i; } }` or `{ int i = 0; while(i < giftGivers.length && !giftGivers[i].name.equals(n)) { i++; } return i; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if (giftGivers[i].name == n)` is wrong, use `if (giftGivers[i].name.equals(n))`

BTW, there is no need to use `NP`. It's C-style, not necessary (actually, pretty dangerous) in Java. Instead of

`for (int i = 0; i < NP; i++)`,

just say `for (int i = 0; i < giftGivers.length; i++)`

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. I actually had to add "break;" in the if statement to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare strings not `==`.

`==` will compare the object references rather than the actual string value.

If you don't care about case, then there is also an equals method that [ignores case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
(giftGivers[i].name == n){
```

should be

```
(giftGivers[i].name.equals(n)){
```

String/Object comparison should use `.equals()` instead of `==`

`==` will check for reference equality. `equals()` check for object equality.

Answer (score 1):

`.equals()` method checks for `equality` of two string objects, `==` operator checks if two refrence variables point to the same String object.

In your case you have to use `.equals()` method

```
if (giftGivers[i].name.equals(n))
```

refer to [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).
Note that if you wanna check if two strings are equal case insensitive use `equalsIgnoreCase()`